# People Picker - user removed from complex picker but not simple one

Tags: 2013, people-picker

I am trying to have a specific user not show up in my Sharepoint People Pickers.

There are two types of people pickers showing up in my SharePoint. Sometimes they have the little icons on the right (people with checkbox and directory) and other times they do not. The simpler people picker automatically starts searching after three characters while the other one requires an exact match or a search.

I have removed a user from my SharePoint 2013:

1. removing them from the UIL
2. removed the OU they are in from my AD Connection settings (User
   profile service)
3. used an ldap query to set the
   peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter property to remove that specific
   user from my people picker.

The user I'm trying to remove no longer appears in the more complex picker but does still appear in the simple people picker.

How can I get this account to get out of my simple people picker?

Comment: It turns out this is a matter of the person being hard-cached in the drop down and there is no low-risk way to remove it. It was only showing up in my people picker and anyone else who had previously seen that user in the people picker. Other new users did not see it. Stored in the registry somewhere.